# Load HTML inside a div via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> i have `bone.php` and `forum.php`
>
> i want to send data to `forum.php` from `bone.php` when i click `#result` via `AJAX`
>
> `forum.php` gets data and does its job inside server and creates an `HTML` page
>
> i want this `HTML` page inside `bone.php #result`.
>
> Is this possible?

i wrote codes like that.

```
$.ajax({

url: "forum.php",
data: 'webpage_id='+webpage_id ,
success: function( ) {
    $('#result').load("forum.php"); 
},
error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
  alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
  console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
  console.log( "Status: " + status );
  console.dir( xhr );
},

})
```

I am getting this messsage `Undefined index: webpage_id in \forum.php on line 15`. However i am sending data. What could be the problem?

What is more interesting is it gives no error and loads the `forum.php` correctly. It just doesn't see the data.

Comment: Have you check `webpage_id` with `console.log(webpage_id);` to ensure that the correct data is being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're performing the request twice, when you do `$('#result').load("forum.php");` in the success block, you're actually running the request a second time. You can do this:

```
$('#result').load("forum.php?webpage_id=" + webpage_id);
```

Or you can do this:

```
$.ajax({

url: "forum.php",
data: 'webpage_id='+webpage_id ,
success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data); 
},
error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
  alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
  console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
  console.log( "Status: " + status );
  console.dir( xhr );
},

})
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with,

`$('#result').load("forum.php");`

this is an ajax call by itself.

```
 $.ajax({

url: "forum.php",
success: function( data ) {
    $('#result').html(data); 
});
```

Equilevant to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({
   url: "forum.php",
   data: 'webpage_id='+webpage_id ,
   success: function(response) {
      $('#result').html(response);
   },
   error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
      alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
      console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
      console.log( "Status: " + status );
      console.dir( xhr );
   }
});
```